# Test and return number only if divisible by a range

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am struggling to determine how to get an answer for the following problem.

What I am attempting to do is take x in a list of numbers (eg 1 to 2,000,000) and divide by a certain range of numbers, y, for example 1 to 20 and return my x value only if it is divisible by all the numbers in the second list.

I have tried the following but when I check the list I am trying to append to it returns a blank

```
divisibles = []

def isdivisible(x):
    for i in range(1,21):
        if x%i!=0:
            return False
    return True

for x in range(1,2000001):
    if isdivisible(x):
        divisibles.append(x)
```

Please could someone help me. 
I am generally struggling with testing for an all case in general.

Thanks.

Comment: you are not checking the divivisibles list. is that what you want to do?

Comment: none of the numbers are divisible by your second list `range(1,21)`. Try some sure range like `range(1,5)` and it will return a llist of int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optimized solution:

```
primes = []
temporary_dividor_check = []
max_nominator_divisible = []
max_div = 1
min_denominator = 1
max_denominator = 21
min_nominator = 1
max_nominator = 20000000
counter = 1

nominators = list(range(min_nominator,max_nominator+1))
denominators = range(min_denominator,max_denominator+1)

def generate_prime_numbers(start,end):
    global primes
    for val in range(start, end + 1): 
        if val > 1: 
            for n in range(2, val//2 + 2): 
                if (val % n) == 0: 
                    break
                else: 
                    if n == val//2 + 1: 
                        primes.append(val) 

generate_prime_numbers(min_denominator,max_denominator+1)

for prime in primes:
    max_div = max_div*prime

while counter * max_div < max_nominator:
    max_nominator_divisible.append(counter*max_div)
    counter += 1

for divisible1 in max_nominator_divisible:
    if divisible1 % max_div == 0:
        for denominator in denominators:
            divisible = divisible % denominator
            if divisible == 0:
                temporary_dividor_check.append(denominator)
                if temporary_dividor_check == list(denominators):
                    print("{} is divisible by all denominators".format(divisible1))                
        temporary_dividor_check = []
```

The simplest but super CPU-hungry (wasteful)

```
nominators = range(1,20000000)
denominators = range(1,21)

temporary_dividor_check = []

for nominator in nominators:
    for denominator in denominators:
        divisible = nominator%denominator
        if divisible == 0:
            temporary_dividor_check.append(denominator)
            if temporary_dividor_check == list(denominators):
                print("{} is divisible by all denominators".format(nominator))                
    temporary_dividor_check = []
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe this might be because no number from 1 to 2000000 is divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20. 
Try calculating the LCM for those numbers first.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine, but the result is indeed an empty list. There are several primes in `range(1, 21)`:

```
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19
```

So, the number that will pass your check *must* be divisible by all of them, so it'll be at least the product of these primes:

```
>>> 2*3*5*7*11*13*17*19
9,699,690
```

You're checking up to 2 million, which isn't nearly enough.

Comment: Note that it is even higher than that, since 9,699,690 is not divisible by 20.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi, of course, it's not divisible by 4 either, for example. It's just something you can quickly check without LCM

Answer (score 3):

Think that it is not possible to find a number in this range that satisfies this function because there are prime numbers such as 1,2,3,5,7 that can only be divided between them and 1. So maybe this function works, but no number fits this divisible range.

Answer (score 2):

First: to check if a number is divisible by all numbers from 1 to 20 you don't need to test all dividers, it is enough to test their Least Common Multiple, which in this case is 232792560. Second: this number is greater than 2000000, so there aren't any numbers in 1 to 2000000 range satisfying your condition.